# Does a question about software architecture using a specific framework belong on Programmers or Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation, software-engineering-se

I have a question about how to best design my React.JS/Flux app.  Does it belong on Stack Overflow or the Programmers community?  I was thinking Programmers, but there's no React or Flux tag on that site, whereas there are on SO.

Comment: My answer is leaning towards Programmers, but it would be helpful if you provided more details regarding your question.  At the moment, you haven't given enough information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hard to say without actually seeing the question, but since you're using words like "design" and "architecture", my guess would be Programmers. Just because we don't have tags for specific frameworks doesn't mean we won't take questions that involve them; odds are the only reason we don't have those tags and SO does is because SO is far bigger than us.

Answer (score 6):

Design questions are most appropriate on Programmers.SE, however, keep the following in mind:

### You must make sure your question is [not too broad.](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/green-fields-blue-skys-and-the-white-board-what-is-too-broad)

We are not going to design your app for you; you must outline what you've done so far, what you're looking to do, and the specific problem that you're having.

Please consider reading [this post on Programmers Meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/design-review-on-topic-or-not) before posting your question there.

### It must actually be a design question.

If it's a design question, it shouldn't be super relevant that you're using React and Flux; that's why those tags don't exist on Programmers. If you're having trouble solving a **specific task using those technologies**, you should be [using Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reactjs-flux/info)

You should also consider reading: [What goes on Programmers.SE? A Guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-programmers-se-a-guide-for-stack-overflow)